# How do I exclude higher MX IP from SpamAssassin?

Tags: spamassassin

... higher priority mail exchange relays some emails to lower priority mail exchange and triggers following w/ SpamAssassin.

```
* -1.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, low
*      trust
*      [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX listed in list.dnswl.org]
```

How can I tell SpamAssassin not to rate/rank/exclude that IP altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer from following URL: [TrustPath - Spamassassin Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/TrustPath)

`trusted_networks 123.12.34.56 123.12.35/24 127.0.0.1`